# Regex to Extract till second or third part of url

Tags: regex, reactjs

I need typescript regex to extract till second part or third part from url from starting.

For example, this is the url I have:

```
https://org.sharepoint.com/sites/controls/_api/web/lists
```

I want my regex to return:

```
https://org.sharepoint.com/sites/controls
```

Found a regex pattern which is:

```
^https?://[^/]+
```

The above regex extracts only till here:

```
https://org.sharepoint.com
```

But, I want to extract till here:

```
https://org.sharepoint.com/sites/controls
```

Comment: Check this as well for details around java regex https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

You could regex split the URL on path separator and then join together the first 3 parts:

```
String url = "https://org.sharepoint.com/sites/controls/_api/web/lists";
String[] parts = url.split("(?<!/)/(?!/)");
String output = parts[0] + "/" + parts[1] + "/" + parts[2];
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
https://org.sharepoint.com/sites/controls
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
`^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\/){3}`

Comment: Hi Vladimir, this regexp is returning in this way:  https://org.sharepoint.com/sites/controls/,controls/

Comment: This is a correct regex. How are you testing? You can use this site https://regexr.com/ to test and learn regex.

Answer (score 0):

## try regexp named groups

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-named-groups

much more readable, much more usable (especially for replacement)  ;)

```js
const string = 'https://org.sharepoint.com/sites/controls/_api/web/lists';
const regex = /^(?<protocol>https?):\/\/(?<domain>[^\/]+)\/(?<route1>[^\/]+)\/(?<route2>[^\/]+)/;
const result = string.match(regex);

resultElement.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({result, "result.groups": result.groups}, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="resultElement"/>
```